# Does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

How come this line of code mine shows an error of

```
 var searchUser = from accnt_user in dbo.Accounts
                             where accnt_user == txtUser.Text && 
                             accnt_Pass == txtPassword.Text
                             select accnt_user;
```

> Error 2   The name 'accnt_Pass' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\John\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PAS\PAS\Login.cs    39  66  PAS
>
> Error 1   The name 'dbo' does not exist in the current context    C:\Users\John\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\PAS\PAS\Login.cs    38  49  PAS

But I already my datacontext linked to it

```
DataClasses1DataContext myDbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext(dbPath);
```

And My DataClasses1DataContext already have this line of code

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Accounts")]
    public partial class Account : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

NOTE: I have not added all of the code in the datacontext since it is long

[image]

Comment: Could you show Account's properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this,   as `accnt_user` this will be the object of Accounts, so you need to access its all member by using `.` operatorr

```
var searchUser = from accnt_user in Accounts
                             where accnt_user.accnt_user== txtUser.Text && 
                             accnt_user.accnt_pass== txtPassword.Text
                             select accnt_user;
```

Comment: What do you mean by yourUserNameProperty? it still gives me an error in Accounts. accnt_user is a column in the table accounts still not working

Comment: You need to replace, yourUserNameProperty with your Account.column name

Comment: accnt_user is the Column name

Comment: I added my table design so that it can easily be understandable

Comment: @user962206 i updated with column, hope now it fix your problem

Comment: There error is still there Error 1 The name 'Accounts' does not exist in the current context C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PAS\PAS\Login.cs 38 49 PAS

Comment: you need to import your namespace, by Using statements. afik you can come to know, by seeing the error

Comment: but it is already imported. it is in my DataContext already. can you give a complete answer?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the context in your query. Also, all column names must be prefixed by the alias defined for the source table or join (unlike SQL, where you can omit the prefix if the column is unique across the set of tables or views in the query).

Change your code to look like this:

```
using(DataClasses1DataContext myDbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext(dbPath))
{
    var searchUser = from user in myDbContext.Accounts
                     where user.accnt_user == txtUser.Text && 
                     user.accnt_Pass == txtPassword.Text
                     select user;

    // do something with searchUser
}
```

This is essentially equivalent to this SQL:

```
select user.*

from dbo.Accounts user

where user.accnt_user = @user and user.accnt_pass = @pass
```